# How to redirect 301 website.pl/page to website.pl/page/?

Tags: .htaccess, http-status-code-301, http-redirect

Is it possible to redirect from website.pl/page to website.pl/page/ ? My .htaccess file is
[my htaccess file](http://paweljanicki.pl/htaccess.txt).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have correct lines in your .htaccess, but you only need to change [L] flag to [L,R=301]

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f   #checks if current URI leads to real file
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(.*)/$    #checks if URI ends by slash, if not goes next
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://paweljanicki.pl/$1/ [L]    #this line changes a URI
```

You need change to:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(.*)/$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://paweljanicki.pl/$1/ [L,R=301]  #or skip 301 code [L,R]
#R=302 by default, but you can set any valid HTTP response status code 300-399
```

The key is that [L] flag doesn't outputs redirect to browser, but Apache will handle *website.pl/page* URI in the shadow with end slash (like *website.pl/page/*).

More info at Apache Docs for [RewriteRule Flags](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/flags.html)

Comment: Can You tell me how can I mark this question as "Answered"? Because I can't find it anywhere.

Answer (score 0):

By default, mod_dir does this for you via the `DirectorySlash` directive (which is set to "On" by default). This means if apache thinks your request is for a directory and is missing a trailing slash, mod_dir will 301 redirect the request to a trailing slash.

However, for virtual directories in a CMS or something, apache won't realize mod_dir needs to handle the trailing slash. So you can try to append a trailing slash to everything doesn't point to an existing file or directory, or for an existing directory, and *turn off mod_dir*.

In the htaccess file in your document root, add these rules (above any type of routing rules that you may already have:

```
DirectorySlash Off

RewriteEngine On

# if request is for a directory
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
# and is missing the trailing slash
RewriteRule ^(.*[^/])$ /$1/ [L,R=301]

# if request isn't for an existing directory or a file
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
# and no trailing slash
RewriteRule ^(.*[^/])$ /$1/ [L,R=301]
```